# uiautomatorviewer on composeUI apps

Tags: java, android, android-jetpack-compose, ui-automation

I'm using the Android studio `uiautomatorviewer` feature in my work,generally I'm obtaining the view's id's ,and then using the information to automate things.
it's working perfect on alot of apps,but no on the compouseui apps.
I know that jetpack compose ui apps does not work with the traditional xml layout file,with view's and etc.... so my question is : is there any way to get a unique identifier(maybe not id,but something else) for a view,so I can get a isolate the desired element from an app?

In the image below:Google play store app,which also built in composeui(at last in the last versions),and my goal is to get any unique identifier to the image element beside of it.

[image]